# Error: xml.sax.SAXParseException while parsing a xml file using wikixmlj

Tags: java, xml

I am parsing the wikipedia xml dump using [wikixmlj](https://github.com/delip/wikixmlj) and getting the following error.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 64243259; columnNumber: 371; JAXP00010004: The accumulated size of entities is "50,000,001" that exceeded the "50,000,000" limit set by "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
        at edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.WikiXMLSAXParser.parse(WikiXMLSAXParser.java:58)
        at edu.virginia.cs.wikirarchy.ParseWikiPage.run(ParseWikiPage.java:36)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So this part of the error is main:

> The accumulated size of entities is "50,000,001" that exceeded the "50,000,000" limit set by "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING".

I am unable to find out a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding three more arguments while running java command solved my problem.

> -DentityExpansionLimit=2147480000 -DtotalEntitySizeLimit=2147480000 -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=2147480000

So, right now I am running my code with the following command.

> nohup java **-DentityExpansionLimit=2147480000 -DtotalEntitySizeLimit=2147480000 -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=2147480000** -Xmx16g -cp "lib/*.jar" -jar dist/WikiRarchy.jar 32 &

The problem was occurring because- by default secure processing limits the number of entities to 50,000,000 and this expansion limit controls entity expansion.