# Disable FEATURE SECURE PROCESSING in Stax Java Parser for XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I am using Stax parser to parse a very large xml file and this the code I have written

```
public class XmlWrite {
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
                                    IOException,XMLStreamException {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    FileReader page = new FileReader("pages142");
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  //factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,false);
    XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(page);
    boolean flag = false;
    int no = 1;
    while(eventReader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    .........
```

This code works fine on a small input file but for a large file it gives the following error

```
       Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: 
       ParseError at [row,col]:[44018907,204]
       Message: JAXP00010004: The accumulated size of entities is 
       "50,000,001" that exceeded the "50,000,000" limit set by 
        "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING".
          at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604) at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:83) at XmlWrite.main(XmlWrite.java:28)
```

I tried the factory.setProperty but that too is not working.Is there any means to disable Secure processing throughout using jvm ?

Comment: I had the same problem. I found the answer:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991043/error-xml-sax-saxparseexception-while-parsing-a-xml-file-using-wikixmlj)

Comment: @animeshpathak Is there a way to disable the limit like that? I have a file so large the limit can't be large enough

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,false)
```

ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/scope.html

Comment: But I tried it and it doesnot work . this statement is in the code in the 4rth line

Comment: Try setFeature(), not setProperty() as you did.

Comment: its still not working :( , here is the error I am getting         
        XmlWrite.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
 factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,false);                    ^
  symbol:   variable XMLConstants
  location: class XmlWrite

Comment: Try with `javax.xml.XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`

Comment: no its still not working... the error is still the same :(... XmlWrite.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
 factory.setFeature(javax.xml.XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,false);
        ^

Comment: The setFeature method is available with a SAXParserFactory, I guess that you need to rewrite your code to use that instead of  XMLInputFactory.

Comment: Is there any way to force FEATURE SECURE PROCESSING in Stax using JVM parameter ?

Comment: Any movement on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using this workaround helped

java -DentityExpansionLimit=2147480000 -DtotalEntitySizeLimit=2147480000 -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=2147480000 Code_Name