# BaseX for Wikipedia Dumps: feature_secure_processing Problem

Tags: xml, parsing, limit, basex

I try to use BaseX (basex.org, no forum, paid help for commercial use cases, no occurrence of the above search term within the help file) db for creating an offline db for a wikipedia text dump (.xml with some 20 GB, unknown number of "pages").

Upon creation of a new db in BaseX, the program imports, very quickly, lots of "entities", every one of these "entities" might be one of the multiple tags, like ...<\title>, and so on, for a far less number of pages.

After the import of 50 million of "entities", I invariably get the error message, "D:/dewiki.xml" (Line 99057203): JAXP00010004: The accumulated size of entities is "50,000,001" that exceeded the "50,000,000" limit set by "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING"", and the db remains empty it seems, i.e. not even the pages processed up to that point in time seem to have been imported.

I have manually searched many of the generic db maintenance, etc. files which come with BaseX, for "feature_secure_processing", but without finding such a string in those multiple files, and there is no setting with regards to it, within the BaseX "Options".

I understand that this string is often used in XML or other environments, in order to prevent web attacks from the outside, but it's obvious that in my use case, I don't need such "protection", but that instead I need to import the whole wikipedia XML dump file, so as BaseX creating the db, together with indexes, and all.

For example, in the much more common "WikiTaxi", content search is not possible but for the current page, and it doesn't even allow for selecting and then copying from the page content, obviously trying to prevent school children from copy-and-paste into their homework; thus, once the limit problem resolved, BaseX (not: XBase) seems to be a far better solution for accessing Wikipedia dumps.

How could I resolve my problem in BaseX?

I am aware of [Error: xml.sax.SAXParseException while parsing a xml file using wikixmlj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991043/error-xml-sax-saxparseexception-while-parsing-a-xml-file-using-wikixmlj) and what has been suggested for Java in there, but I don't know Java, or any other programming language, so that answer doesn't help me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by Java’s default XML parser. If you use the graphical user interface, you can use the built-in BaseX XML parser by enabling the "Use XML internal parser" option on the Parsing tab in the database creation dialog.

If you want to stick with the default parser of Java, you’ll need to pass on system properties when launching BaseX, as described in the answer to the StackOverflow question you have posted.

Comment: Thank you so much, dear Mr. Grün (=creator of BaseX), this did the import (GUI with dialogs). Unfortunately, even dialogue "Parsing-Use internal-Parse DTDs "and entities"(!), chop whitespace" put it all in ONE (chopped) file/record (original=about360million lines), did NOT populate different (SQL?) fields with the data,according to the tags; I would also be happy with just 1record/file per "page",by tag "<page>",and which would comprise theother tags/data of that page,but there is NO field in the dialogue to enter such a "record-separator" by which to parse / distribute into files or records.

Comment: The BaseX mailing list is probably a better place to discuss further questions.